# how should I add textfield ie jump pagination in views mini pagination of drupal

Tags: views, paging

I have created views of gallery by view. View has provided pagination option. I choose mini pager.

I want to implement **Jump Pagination** here. How should I add in view pagination?

[image]

Comment: I've update my answer with new module (Pretty Pagination). I hope it helps.

Comment: You could just override the theme function for this... https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/theme_views_mini_pager/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Pretty Pagination](https://drupal.org/project/prettypagination) module . I think This is what you are looking for.

> This module extends the default pagination into a more flexible format. It allows the user to jump to any specific page in the content just by entering the desired page number in an input box and hitting the ENTER key. The result is easier navigation, especially with sites where the content is spread over numerous pages.

Another module is

[Pagerer](https://drupal.org/project/pagerer) module. Using this module you can give direct input of the page to go to through a jQuery UI Slider.

> Pagerer is a module providing a collection of pager themes to enhance Drupal and Views standard pagers.
>
> **Features**:
>
> - multi-pane pager
> - Views pager plugin
> - control whether to display links to pages, to items, or to item
>   ranges
> - **direct input of the page to go to through an input widget**
> - selection of the page to go to through a jQuery UI slider
> - selection of the page to go to through a client-side scrolling pager
> - links to progressively more distant pages (like +10, + 20, +100,
>   +200)
> - adaptive logic links
> - specify text to be used to render page separators (like a vertical
>   bar) and page breakers (like an ellipsis)
> - supports Views' AJAX enabled pager